# Glossaries: How to determine in which glossary an entry is defined?

Tags: glossaries

I use the Glossaries package to create both an glossary and a list of acronyms. Now I need a way to determine whether a given term is defined in the glossary (`\newglossaryentry {term} ...`) or in the acronym list (`\newacronym  {term} ...`).

The package does provide `\ifglsentryexists` but it only checks for general existence of the entry.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo} {name = {Foo}, description = {``foo'' glossary entry}}
\newacronym{bar} {BAR} {``bar'' acronym}

\begin{document}

If \gls{foo} is a normal glossary entry a ``X'' should follow, if
its an acronym we want its long form (\\glsentrylong{foo}) instead: ???

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the form you are using `glossaries` there is no distinction between `foo` and `bar`: both are of type `main`, as `\newacronym` will only call `\newglossaryentry` with type set to `\acronymtype`. But without the `acronym` package option `\acronymtype` is `main`, i.e., the default glossary type. You can see this in:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{foo} {name = {Foo}, description = {``foo'' glossary entry}}
\newacronym{bar} {BAR} {``bar'' acronym}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

If \gls{foo} is a normal glossary entry a ``X'' should follow, if
its an acronym we want its long form (\\glsentrylong{foo}) instead: ???

\gls{bar}

\glsentrytype{foo}, \glsentrytype{bar}

\acronymtype

\printglossary

\end{document}
```

As shown here, in general the type can be inferred from `\glsentrytype{<name>}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact, I do use the `acronym` package option in my actual document and just forgot to add it to the MWE.